# Ordering Sql result based on number of token matches from RLIKE

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to implement a simple search query, where I am splitting the search text into tokens and then returning all results that contain any of the tokens, I am using RLIKE 'token1|token2|token3|...', this is working correctly and returning all the result, but now I would want to Order the result by the numbers of tokens from the RLIKE that matches, is that anyway possible anyway? thanks in advance.

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p 
WHERE p.title RLIKE 'token1|token2|token3';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `LIKE` for each of the tokens in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY (p.title LIKE '%token1%') +
         (p.title LIKE '%token2%') +
         (p.title LIKE '%token3%') DESC
```

Each of the boolean expressions `p.title LIKE '%tokenX%'` evaluates to `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

Comment: well, the number of tokens is variable not fixed, as it is being made from the user input.

Comment: @adn.911 you can expand the ORDER BY clause for as many tokens as there are.